# Se debe pedir al usuario que ingrese la cantidad de números (n) entre los que desea buscar el mayor y menor de todos ellos en Python

Tags: python

estoy intentado resolver este problema y solamente logro hacer que me muestre el mayor de todos los números ingresados, pero por mas que he intentado no logro concretar la idea para hacer que me muestre el menor.
Como podría hacer para que me muestre el menor ? finalmente pude :)
Así quedo el código

```
entrada = int(input("Ingrese cuantos numeros va a ingresar: "))
a=0
menor=0
for i in range(1,entrada+1):
  num = int(input(f"Ingrese el numero {i}: "))
  if num > a:
    a = num 
  if i == 1:
    menor = num
  if num < menor:
    menor = num
 
print(f"El mayor de todos es {a} y el menor es {menor}")
```

Comment: Es muy similar a como encuentras el valor mayor. En tu caso pones en `a` el valor mayor. Agrega otra variable para el valor menor antes del for.`menor = 0`. Agrega otro if despues del if de `a` pero comparando `num < menor` y asignando `menor = num`

Comment: Hola, corregí el código como me lo indicaste, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo, siempre me devuelve el valor de 0.

Comment: publica lo que modificaste para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Listo, ya la publique nuevamente

Comment: Kaz Miller se refería a que edites la pregunta (el boton editar está abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) y agregues allí la modificación que hiciste.

Comment: A perdón jajaja ya la edito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu error se encuentra en el recorrido del for, adjunto el siguiente código, separando por un lado la pedida de números y por otro la búsqueda del mayor para que así se entienda mejor el proceso y quizás entiendas mejor en lo que estés fallando. Cualquier duda no dudes en preguntarme! :)

```
entrada = int(input("Ingrese cuantos numeros va a ingresar: "))
lista_nums = []    #Creamos una lista vacía para guardar los números
for i in range(0,entrada):
    # El range es 0 ya que las listas empiezan en 0
    n = int(input(f"Ingrese el numero {i+1}: "))
    lista_nums.append(n)    # Agregamos el numero introducido a la lista
    

# Teniendo ya la lista con todos nuestro números podemos recorrerla para encontrar el mayor y el menor

mayor = 0    # El mayor será 0 para empezar a recorrer y comparar
menor = lista_nums[0]   # El menor será el primero de la lista a 
                        # menos que el bucle establezca algo 
                        # diferente
for num in lista_nums:
    # Si el numero de la lista es mayor que nuestra variable mayor,
    # entonces mayor pasa a ser dicho numero , sino seguimos recorriendo
    if num > mayor:
        mayor = num 
    elif num < menor:
        menor = num

# Terminado el bucle se imprimirá solo el mayor que será aquel contenido en la variable mayor y menor
print(f"El mayor de todos es {mayor}, y el menor de todos es {menor}")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, me ayudaste bastante, cuando tenga una alguna inquietud no dudare en preguntarte :)